# Laravel: Only specific fields of a relation that I query with latestOfMany

Tags: laravel

I wonder why I can't display specific fields of the relation (**ModelARelation1**) of **ModelA** in my query below. The query below gives me all fields / columns. But I only need the fields `id` and `created_at`, But I will get `null` if i use the line of code: `->with('latestRequest:id, created_at')`. What I doing wrong? I used Laravel 9.

**ModelA**

```php
public function requests(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(ModelARelation1::class);
}

public function latestRequest()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ModelARelation1::class)->latestOfMany('created_at');
}
```

**Controller**

```php
$entity = 'someEntityAsString';

$paginator = ModelA::query()
    ->when($entity, fn($q) => $q->where('entity', $entity))
    ->withCount("records")
    ->with('latestRequest')
    ->paginate($this->paginationLimit());
```

Comment: You need to include the Foreign Key: `->with('latestRequest:id,created_at,foreign_id')` (replace `foreign_id` with whatever column connects the 2 tabales), otherwise the returned result will be `null` or an empty `Collection`.

Comment: From the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns, *"When using this feature, you should always include the `id` column **and any relevant foreign key columns** in the list of columns you wish to retrieve."*